# Pairing fields in a table for a select query

Tags: php, mysql

[image: screenshot of database structure]

Hi, so I have this database project I'm working on that involves transcribing archival sources to make them more accessible.

I'm revamping the database structure, so I can make the depiction of the archival data more accurate to the manuscript sources. As part of that, I have this new table, which has both the labels/titles for columns of data in the documents, plus a "used"field which acts both as a flag for if the field is used, and also for what position it should be in left to right (As the order changes sometimes).

I'm wondering if there's a way to pair the columns together so I can do a query that - when asking for a single row to be returned= sorts the "used" functions numerically (returning all the ones that aren't -1), and *also* returns all the "label" fields also sorted into the same order (eg if guns_used is 2, and men_used is 1 and ship_name_position is 0, the query will put them in the correct order and *also* return guns_label, men_label and shipname_label in the correct order).

I'm also working with/around wordpress, so I have the contents of the whole wpdb thing available to me too.

I'm hoping to be able to "pair" the fields in some way so that if I order one set, the other gets ordered as well.

Edit:
I really would prefer to find a way to do this in a query but until I find a way to do that I'm going to

a)Select the entire row that I need
b)Have a long series of if statements- one for each pair of _label/_used fields- and assigning the values I want to the position in the array indicated by the value of the _used field.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. Can you add examples of the table data and examples of the output you want?

Comment: @rovr138 I don't have any data in the table yet. I'm working on the code for pulling data/out putting it in, I've been noodling this while I work on it.

the Label fields are strings, they could be things like "Number of Guns" or "Crew" or "Crewmembers", _used fields are integers- going from -1 (not used) to 15 or so (if all used).

Comment: @rovr138

what I'd like to get out is an array that contains all the _labels fields whose associated _used fields have a value greater than -1 (indicating they are in use)- sorted according to the values of their associated _used fields.